# How do I bind `roles/bigquery.jobUser` to a GCP project in terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to run a query in BigQuery, and am getting:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/my-project/jobs?prettyPrint=false: Access Denied: Project my-project: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project my-project.
```

So, I need to give my service account the [BigQuery Job User](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#bigquery.jobUser) role in `my-project`.

Initially, I thought that I would bind it to the *dataset* so wrote the following, but the binding needs to go to the *project*. However, in [the terraform docs for the google provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs) I can't see a similar pattern for binding things to projects.

Here's what I had when I thought it was bound to the dataset:

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset_iam_binding" "dataset_job_user" {
  dataset_id = google_bigquery_dataset.dataset.dataset_id
  role   = "roles/bigquery.user"
  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.my_service_account.email}"
  ]
}
```

How can I bind this role at the project level in terraform?

Comment: I feel like the actual query is irrelevant noise, since any query would product the same result, and I don't like to include a lot of irrelevant background. If anything, I could get rid of the error itself (to which my argument might also apply)?

Comment: I think one of the keys is to post problems that can be reproduced easily without trying to figure out missing details. I don't actually know why you were downvoted, just suggestions from my years on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Because there's no top-level resource inteh sidebar of the docs, I had overlooked the project resource in the terraform provider. This has a corresponding [`google_project_iam_binding`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam#google_project_iam_binding) and needed to bind to this instead.

The correct terraform code is:

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "project_bigquery_job_user" {
  project = "${var.project}"
  role    = "roles/bigquery.jobUser"
  members = [
    "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.my_service_account.email}"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but be careful using that resource. Authoritative for a given role and will remove other members that were granted that role that are not part of the `members` list. I recommend using `google_project_iam_member` instead.

Comment: Thanks @John Hanley, that's a good spot - I'll update next time I'm in office.